# Storybook 6 - how to set array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I want to pass data props for my Badge component and I have problem with `array` method from `addon-knobs` library. Data prop is an array of objects and I am trying to pass it like this:

```
const data = [
  object('First', {color: '#fa2dac', text: 'RSS'}),
  object('Second', {color: '#fa2dac', text: 'RSS'}),
];
```

Which gives me result that I have 2 fields (first and second) but when I want to change values inside they don't update on screen.

Second try:

```
const data = array('List of items', [
  object('First', {color: '#fa2dac', text: 'RSS'}),
  object('Second', {color: '#fa2dac', text: 'RSS'}),
]);
```

Which gives me same result but instead of 2 I am getting 3 fields and the third one has got value `[object Object]`

And third try:

```
const data = array('List of items', [
  {color: '#fa2dac', text: 'RSS'},
  {color: '#fa2dac', text: 'RSS'},
]);
```

Which gives me only filed with `[object Object]`

How to add knobs with array of objects and have fully working updating?

Comment: can you share your code where you try to update the objects?

Comment: Updated, please look

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm unable to identify the issue with your code :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I moved data array into component and it works perfect now. The only thing I have noticed that array of objects must be passed with `object` method and now it works and refreshes the page.

```
export const Primary = () => {
  const data = object('List of items', [
    {color: '#fa2dac', text: 'RSaS'},
    {color: '#fa2dac', text: 'RSaS'},
  ]);
  return <Badge data={data}></Badge>;
};
```

Comment: Where do you import the object method from?

Comment: import {object} from '@storybook/addon-knobs';

Comment: You need to add this line to your addons in main.js file and ofc install it first '@storybook/addon-knobs/register',

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-knobs

Answer (score 2):

With 6.4.19 Storybook, you should map your options. Currently, @storybook/addon-knobs is deprecated.

```
  argTypes: {
    data: {
      control: {
        type: 'select',
        labels: {
          first: 'First Option',
          second: 'Second Option'
        }
      },
      options: ['first', 'second'],
      mapping: {
        first: {color: '#fa2dac', text: 'RSS'},
        second: {color: '#fa2dac', text: 'RSS'}
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

using "@storybook/addon-knobs": "6.0.21", "@storybook/angular": "6.0.21",

I have an array of objects, that I pass as an @Input() links: Links[]; With this setup, you will be able to past any JSON object.
Angular component:

```
export class HeaderComponent  {
  @Input() links: Link[] = [];
  @Output() navigate = new EventEmitter<any>();

  linkClicked(link: Link){
    this.navigate.emit(link);
  }
}
```

import { text, number, boolean, array, select, object } from '@storybook/addon-knobs';

```
import { HeaderComponent, Link } from './header.component';

export default {
  title: 'HeaderComponent'
}
let links: Link[] = [{name: "link one", route: ""}] 
export const primary = () => ({
  moduleMetadata: {
    imports: []
  },
  component: HeaderComponent,
  props: {
    links: object("links",links)
  }
```

})

[image]